# Pycharm FastAPI configuration works on Run, stalls on Debug when adding a breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, fastapi, python-poetry

I just created a new Python project using Poetry. It's pretty simple, this is my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-app"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["me"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
fastapi = "^0.104.1"
supabase = "^2.0.3"
uvicorn = "^0.24.0.post1"
pydantic = {extras = ["dotenv"], version = "^1.10.2"}

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
mypy = "^1.5.1"
pre-commit = "^3.5.0"
pytest = "^7.4.3"
pytest-cov = "^4.1.0"
```

This is my project structure: The entry point is `web_server.py`.

[image: project structure]

web_server.py

```
import uvicorn
from app.config.rest.api import create_fastapi_app

app = create_fastapi_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

`api.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app.config.rest.endpoints.router import api_router


def create_fastapi_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI(title="My API")

    app.include_router(api_router, prefix="/api")

    return app
```

And `router.py`:

```
from fastapi import Header, APIRouter, Depends

from app.config.rest.endpoints.meta import router as meta_router


def custom_headers(
        user_id: str = Header(examples=["postman"], convert_underscores=False),
):
    return


no_headers_router = APIRouter()
headers_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(custom_headers)])
no_headers_router.include_router(meta_router, tags=["meta"])

api_router = APIRouter()
api_router.include_router(no_headers_router)
api_router.include_router(headers_router)
```

I can start my web server by running `poetry run uvicorn  --app-dir ./src app.web_server:app --reload` in the console. I can also start the web server from PyCharm using the following config:

[image: Run config]

This works as expected:

[image: API running]

It also works if I debug instead of run this same configuration. However, if I add a breakpoint (doesn't matter where), PyCharm doesn't start the API and hangs in there forever. The endpoints are not accessible either as I guess the startup process has not finished. For example, adding a breakpoint in `uvicorn.run(app)` results in the app hanging forever:

[image: Debug configuration]

I would assume that there's an issue with the Debug configuration if it would not start the server, but this only happens if I set any breakpoints in code. If there are no breakpoints, the configuration launches the app as expected.

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading Python to 3.11, I had the same issue and for me it helped.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35595806)